# monitoring the size of an SQL Server connection pool

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, connections, connection-pool

We are trying to track down a performance issue.

One theory we have is that we are running out of connections in the connection pool.

Is there a way to monitor the size of a connection pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these performance counters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503.aspx

Some of these counters require a change to the app.config file

Answer (score 0):

Not really. This is a client side thing (the pool), not a server side thing. Except with leaky cionnections (open until gc kicks in) I have never seen that exhausted. I am note sure where the default limit is - I think around 200 or so.